# Do default namespaces in XML really need a URI?

Tags: xml, namespaces

Since URIs do not really refer to a web location, why do default namespaces in XML need a URI? 
Why can't the first appearance of any element be put in some standard default namespace?

Comment: URI's are picked since they contain a domain name, which is unique and cannot be used by someone else in the world. The requirement is just uniqueness - and using a URI based on a domain name satisfies that need

Comment: Well , Uniqueness can be accepted as a reason for Namespace URI's since if we use names , they can be repeated.
But Just say , if there's no name for a Default namespace ; every 1st occurrence of an element just goes into some standard Default Namespace. Hence , No body can repeat it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [namespaces rec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-namespaces) requires URI references for namespaces, so the status of some namespace as a default makes no difference.  As for why any of them have to be URIs when in general they aren't dereferencable (RDF is non-compliant in this respect), why ask why?  At Some Point, Someone Thought It Would Be A Good Idea, and lo, It Was Made So.

However, it's possible that you may be confusing a default namespace with no namespace at all.  There is no "standard default" namespace.

The default namespace in a document is specified with the 'xmlns' attribute (no colon, no suffix) and can have any URI-lookalike value the author pleases.  There is no standard value that it must have.

Furthermore, the xmlns attribute specification is optional.  If it isn't present - and it's allowed to be absent - then there is no default namespace at all.