# Where do xmlns URIs point to?

Tags: xml

I often see XML documents with the `xmlns` attribute pointing to what appears to be an online resource - i.e. `http://...` or `https://...`. But going to these resources in a browser always returns errors.

What is the value of the `xmlns` attribute actually (if it's not a URI)? Alternatively, why can I not just access these resources by a browser?

=== EDIT

The best answer I've seen is here: [In DTDs, why are namespaces given as a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201678/in-dtds-why-are-namespaces-given-as-a-url)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201678/in-dtds-why-are-namespaces-given-as-a-url

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043391/do-default-namespaces-in-xml-really-need-a-uri

Comment: Not to mention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974378/what-does-namespace-uri-exactly-means

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271786/why-are-xml-namespaces-http-addresses

Comment: question. what would happen if you instead put a GUID in the namespace? or would the XML parse explicitly be wanting a URI schemed namespace? On that note, are both https and http allowed?

Answer (score -1):

The best answer that I found was to the question linked to above as 'duplicate'. However since the best answer (in my opinion) is not the accepted answer; here is a link to the answer I found most helpful (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760645/3114742)

> When you ask why a standard is the way it is, there are two possible
> interpretations of your question: (a) what are the perceived benefits
> of the design choice that was made, and (b) what was the historical
> sequence of events that led to this design being adopted over other
> designs.
>
> Clearly, using HTTP-like URIs gives uniqueness. But that could also
> have been achieved in other ways, for example by inventing a new URI
> scheme. I think that if you trace the arguments that were made at the
> time, you will find that many of the people advocating the use of
> HTTP-style URIs were also advocating that namespace URIs should be
> dereferencable, perhaps to a schema or to some other kind of document.
> Indeed, it's W3C policy for its own namespaces that there is always a
> document that can be retrieved when you type the namespace URI into a
> browser, and that it should tell you something useful about the
> namespace.
>
> So I suspect the fact that we use URIs that look deferenceable but
> don't define any semantics for what happens when they are dereferenced
> is in fact the result a committee compromise between two or more
> opposing camps. But you'd have to do some proper historical research
> to confirm that.